# AWS CDK How do you swap endpoint API mappings on a pre-existing custom domain name in API Gateway (V1)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm trying to swap endpoint mappings for a pre-existing custom domain name using the AWS Python CDK. This is so that blue and green deployments of an API Gateway (V1 as it is REST) can update the endpoint mapping for a custom domain name. i.e. so the API Gateway with domain_name blue.api.example.com is mapped to api.example.com and when the new API Gatewy with domain_name green.api.example.com is deployed it then updates the map to associate green with it instead.

Here is the CDK code:

```
main_domain_name = apigw.DomainName(
            self, "construct-id", certificate=certificate, domain_name="api.example.com"
        )
main_domain_name.add_base_path_mapping(api_gateway) # api-gateway has domain_name e.g. blue.api.example.com
```

I am getting the following error when redeploying the new stack, it's not happy with the empty base path mapping being the same:

```
The stack named xxxx-xxxxx failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "Base path already exists for this domain name (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 409, Request ID: XXX)" (RequestToken: XXXX, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)
```

I have also tried passing the mapping into the DomainName constructor and get the same issue.

Does anyone know a way to get around this or encountered this issue before in CDK?

Currently thinking of building a Custom Resource to use the AWS SDK to manually delete and then add the mapping but would rather not do this if raw CDK can be used.

Thanks!

---

UPDATE Jan 2024

Worked around this using a CDK Custom Resource to make AWS SDK calls within the CDK.

The issue is that the CDK and CloudFormation currently only support "add" functionality for domain name base path mapping. The AWS SDK and CLI support "update", "delete" domain name base path mapping functionality.